# Modify value at the time of binding DataGrid Compact Framwork

Tags: compact-framework

I have used BindingSource to bind DataGrid in my window 6.5 application. But problem is that I want to change the text of a column from Int to string while grid is binding.

If you look at below code I am binding DataGrid with Designation which value is 502 but I need to display "SE" instead, I cant take that value in my Candidate object so I need to modify DataGrid at runtime. I dont know how can I achieve this. Please help . Thanks

```
cand.Add(new Candidate { ID = 10, Name = "Andrew", Designation       =501 ,DCode="SSE" });
        cand.Add(new Candidate { ID = 11, Name = "Peter", Designation = 502 , DCode="SE"});
        DataGridTableStyle myDataGridTableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        myDataGridTableStyle.MappingName = "Candidate";
        DataGridTextBoxColumn colA = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        colA.MappingName = "Name";
        colA.HeaderText = "Field A";
        colA.Width = 50;
        DataGridTextBoxColumn colB = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        colB.MappingName = "Designation";
        colB.HeaderText = "Position Holding";
        colB.Width = 100;
        //dataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber.
        DataGridTextBoxColumn colC = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        colC.MappingName = "DCode";
        colC.HeaderText = "Code Position";
        colC.Width = 50;

        myDataGridTableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(colA);
        myDataGridTableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(colB);
        myDataGridTableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(colC);

        myBindingSource.DataSource = cand.ToBindingList();
        myDataGridTableStyle.MappingName = myBindingSource.GetListName(null);
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Clear(); // Recommended on MSDN in the code examples.
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(myDataGridTableStyle);
        dataGrid1.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the DCode property a slave to your Designation property so that:

```
Canidate c = new Candidate();
c.Designation = 501;
print(c.DCode);//outputs "SSE"
```

then you can bind to DCode when you just want the string interpretation of Designation.